# PDF viewer web part

Tags: web-part, pdf

I'm new with sharepoint 2013 
Does anyone know pdf viewer webpart for sharepoint 2013 for free
Please help me.

Comment: what exactly is your question? Do you just want to view Pdf documents in SharePoint WebPages?

Comment: Hi varun i want a webpart which can view pdf files from my library perfectly

Comment: you want to display one PDF file in one page?

Comment: you know there were some solutions like SPSolution.PDFViewer for sharepoint 2010 but i searched for sharepoint 2013 and i didn't find any thing

Comment: Our company want this webpart to viewing pdf files(Daily Newspapers wich converted to pdf) from our library(newspaperlib)

Answer (score 14):

**Use content editor web part:-** [(http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/03/embedding-pdfs-into-sharepoint-2010-pages/)](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/03/embedding-pdfs-into-sharepoint-2010-pages/)

First you need to find the URL to the PDF that you wish to view, after that you are ready to go!

Step 1)

Add a Content Editor Web Part to the page

Step 2)

Click on the ‘Edit HTML Source’ button for the Content Editor Web Part (not the page)

Step 3)

Add the following code:

```
<object><embed src="FILENAME.PDF" height="850" width="850"

 type="application/pdf"></embed></object>
```

Where:

src = The URL of the file, remember to put in a server relative URL to this!

height = height of the rendered PDF

width = width of the rendered PDF

Click on Save and you should see your PDF rendered

**OR Use page viewer webpart:-**[(http://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/how-to-embed-a-pdf-document-in-a-sharepoint-wiki-page-with-a-page-viewer-webpart/)](http://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/10/16/how-to-embed-a-pdf-document-in-a-sharepoint-wiki-page-with-a-page-viewer-webpart/)

Steps:

1. Upload the PDF document to an appropriate SharePoint library and copy the URL in a Notepad. The URL is needed later.
2. Open the Wiki page where the document has to be embedded and click on the Edit icon at the top-left.
3. Click on the location or bring the cursor to the location in the Wiki page where you’d like to embed the PDF.
4. Click on the Editing Tools > Insert tab at the top of the page ().
5. Click on Web Part.
6. Select Media and Content in the Categories list box on the left of the page and select Page Viewer from the Web Parts list. Click on Add. This will insert the Page Viewer web part at the location of the cursor in the page.
7. Hover over the inserted Page Viewer web part. Click on the drop down button and click the Edit Web Part option.
8. Paste the URL, give a title and specify a height for the web part and click OK. You are done! The PDF will now appear as a document in a window and Adobe Reader’s normal features like zoom, pan, print etc. would be available to interact with the document.

**Another way on Microsoft website**:- [(http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/embed-office-documents-and-pdf-files-on-a-website-HA102845475.aspx#_Toc362267437)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/embed-office-documents-and-pdf-files-on-a-website-HA102845475.aspx#_Toc362267437)

Comment: Thank you for helping but will it show all of my pdf files our just one?

Comment: Do you mean all pages in file? Then, YES

Comment: If you mean for every PDF file, then NO. You will have to repeat the above procedure for every PDF file you want to display.

Comment: You mean N webpart for N pdf file? imean for example 20 webpart for 20 pdf file?

Comment: No, for example:1 content editor webpart with N --> <object><embed src="FILENAME.PDF" height="850" width="850"

 type="application/pdf"></embed></object> --> for N PDFs.

Comment: The page viewer webpart solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: The Content Editor web part does not have an 'Edit HTML Source' button in 2013. Are you thinking of the Script Editor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CQWP (Custom Query Web Part) and create your own ItemStyle.xsl. Then simply add the CQWP to your site and select the source library and the Content Type you wish to show.

With this solution you can have one Web Part serving N listitems in SharePoint libraries, you can also query for Content Types on the whole site if you wish to show PDF documents from multiple libraries.

You can find more information about how to create a custom ItemStyle on the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb447557(v=office.14).aspx), and there are also a few tutorials out there (like this one http://www.cwheeler76.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=9a19060b-0efe-4368-8360-b07d23dc5c7b&ID=6&Web=916c3f13-7f62-4b71-b302-6fd9106b4bb2).

If you want to iterate multiple PDF's from multiple site collections and have a search service running you can use a simmilar Web Part - SCRWP (Search Core Results Web Part) to iterate all documents from index.

On a side note, i wouldn't add to mutch <embed> tags to a site - this can have a big performance impact on the browser - maybe you'll find a solution with thumbnails.

Comment: Hi & thank you for helping me but i got an error when i wanted to add this webpart from browser and didn't add it (IE 10, Chrome)

Comment: What error did you get? Check the Sharepoint Logs for Erros in your XSL.