# Create enterprise wiki page with embed code

Tags: csom, enterprise-wiki

We are looking at migrating our very old ScrewTurn Wiki into SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Wiki site.  One key features in the original system is the inline PDF viewing with html embed object.

I was able to do the same thing with instruction from [PDF Viewer webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105867/pdf-viewer-web-part) by editing a wiki page directly.

Now we to create the same thing via code, preferably CSOM.  I have tried to read the ListItem of the page I have made with embedded code, and I can't seem to see anything containing the embedded code at all.

Any one have idea which property I need to look at?  Or I need REST or even Server Side object model instead?